# Call parent class' constructor function via call()

Tags: javascript

```
// Parent class
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.sayHello = function() {
  console.log("Hello. My name is " + this.name);
};
Person.prototype.sayGoodbye = function() {
  console.log("Goodbye!");
};

// Child class
function Student(name, gpa) {   
  Person.call(this, name);// I'm confused what does keyword 'this' refer to?
  this.gpa = gpa;
}

// create child object
let john = new Student("john",3.5);
```

Does the keyword 'this' refer to object john or Person.prototype?

Comment: 'this' keyword refer to the Student object you've created and assign it to john.

Answer (score 1):

The `new` operator preceding `Student("john",3.5);` creates a new instance object, prototyped on the following function's `prototype` property, before calling the function with the newly created object as its `this` value. ( Refer to [`new operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) documentation on MDN for more detail).)

So the `this` in

```
 Person.call(this, name);
```

is the student object created and returned by `new` before being stored in the `john` variable.

`Student` code then calls the `Person` function with its own `this` value so that the `Person` constructor can add "Person" type properties to the `Student` object before returning from `Student`.

Worth noting:

- The example shows how the construction of class objects was undertaken before implementation of the `class` keyword in JavaScript
- This particular example does not implement inheritance of `Person.prototype` properties by `Student` objects. This was sometime implemented using a dummy `Person` object as the prototype of `Student`, using code similar to:

  ```
  Student.prototype = new Person();
  Student.prototype.constructor = Student;
  ```

  The shortcomings and limitations of this practice at least contributed to the introduction of [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class) constructor functions in ECMAScript.

Answer (score -1):

Here to make Student a child class you need to extend it to the Person class:

```
class Person {
  var name;
  constructor(name) {
     this.name = name;
  }
  sayhello(){
        console.log("Hello. My name is " + this.name);
  }
  sayGoodbye(){
        console.log("Goodbye!");
  }
}



class Student extends Person {
     getName(){
         return this.name;
     }
}

student = new Student("Jhon");
```

The 'this' keywords refers to the current object. You can call methods of the parent class from the child class using the child class object itself as you are using extend keywords.

This is a simple example of inheritance.

Comment: Is this answering the question asked?

Comment: the given example is itself wrong as there are no classes given then how can we refer to the which object. anyways i mentioned the purpose of `this` keyword